# How to wrap a singleton class using pybind11?

Tags: pybind11

I have a singleton class in C++ (no public constructor, C++ programmers call class.instance() to create the singleton or return the existing one).

I'd prefer to hide this at the Python level. If I was writing a Python singleton, I'd handle that in `__new__`. If a class has no public constructor I don't think I can create an `__init__` wrapper (my attempts at that have failed). I saw no mention of `__new__` in the pybind11 docs (though might have missed it, and Google seems happy to elide underscores an return pages containing "new", with no mention of `__new__`).

Is there a singleton recipe for pybind11 (or even Boost.Python)?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to expose `__init__` if you don't instantiate your class from Python. As for your question, you can try something like this:

```
py::class_<CppSingle>(mod, "Single")
.def_static("__new__", [](py:object) { return CppSingle::instance(); )},
 py::return_value_policy::reference_internal);
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming your singleton class looks like this:

```
class MySingleton{
    // private constructor here
public:
    MySingleton& instance();    
};
```

You could wrap it up like so:

```
    py::class_<MySingleton, std::unique_ptr<MySingleton, py::nodelete>>(m, "MySingleton")
    .def(py::init([](){ 
        return std::unique_ptr<MySingleton, py::nodelete>>(&MySingleton::instance());
    });
```

Key here is to use `py::nodelete` so the destructor is not referenced (and your c++ singleton is not destructed when the unique_ptrs used by multiple python instances are garbage-collected).

That code also relies on the custom constructor support introduced with pybind11 v2.2.0 (August 31st, 2017) which allows us to wrap a lambda instead of a constructor inside the init.

References
 - [Pybind11 v2.2.0 changelog](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v2-2-0-august-31-2017)
 - [Pybind11 doc about custom constructors](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html?highlight=singleton#custom-constructors)
 - [Pybind11 doc on non-public destructors](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#non-public-destructors)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about pybind11, but I believe it should be possible to wrap your class using Boost.Python. (Your question reads "or even Boost.Python"...)

Use `noncopyable` and/or `no_init`:

```
class_<Klass, boost::noncopyable>("Klass", no_init)
    .staticmethod("instance")
    ;
```

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2004-March/006647.html